# Can SIGABRT be generate by a key command (just like SIGINT ctrl+c)?

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to this topics of signals so would like to know if SIGABRT be generate by a key command like SIGINT when ctrl+c is pressed.
Any help would be great.
heres the code i have written:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int c=0;
void hand(int signo)
{
    if(signo==SIGINT)
    {
        c++;
        printf("Why the fuck are you interputing me?\n");
    }
    if(signo==SIGABRT)
    {
        printf("Why the fuck are you aborting me?bitch!!\n");
        kill(getpid(),SIGABRT);
        //exit(0);
    }
    if(signo==SIGKILL)
    {
        printf("Why the fuck are you killing me?\n");
        kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
    }
    if(c>5)
    {
        printf("You execute too many fucking times!!..so now    die\n");
        kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    if(signal(SIGINT,hand)==SIG_ERR)
        printf("Error in catching SIGINT\n");
    if(signal(SIGABRT,hand)==SIG_ERR)
        printf("Error in catching SIGABRT\n");
    if(signal(SIGKILL,hand)==SIG_ERR)
        printf("Error in catching SIGKILL\n");
    for(i=1;i<50;i++) 
    {  
        printf("I'm sleeping...\n");     
        sleep(2 );     
        printf("SIGINT sent %d times",c);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler, and for which system? C is used with variety of platforms, and some of them might not even support signals.

Comment: the system i'm using is linux and the compiler is GCC

Answer (score 0):

Do the following command from terminal

`killall -SIGABRT <your-process>`

Comment: im actuall writting a C code to catch the abort signal so wanted to which key to press (ctrl+c)

Comment: While running your executable, take another terminal and run the above terminal.

Comment: still you need keyboard shortcut?